# Add logos in upper left and right corner of Malmoe theme in beamer

Tags: beamer, textpos

I'm trying to add a logo into the upper left and upper right corners of the Malmoe theme.  I'm sure it doesn't matter, but just in case, I'm using the Whale color theme.  I've tried several things, but the following is what got me the closest to what I want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\title{can't get this to work}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\addtobeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{}{
    \begin{textblock*}{25mm}(0,0.25cm)
        \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{psumarks/pms287-noBorder.png}
    \end{textblock*}}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Title}
     Why isn't this working?
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, the color in the section of the slide that I want to put the logo in disappears. I've attached an example below.  The upper left should be black, not white.  And yes, I realize that the logo in this particular example is larger than the section itself would be, but that's not the case for the presentation that I'm trying to use this for.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, ignore the black border around the slide.

[image]

Comment: But then the logos will interfere with the headline and the eventual frame title. Are you sure this is the desired position using this theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option, defining a `headline` template to accomodate the logos at the desired locations:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\def\includelogoi{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\def\includelogoii{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{mytheme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{%
        \smash{\raisebox{-\height}{\includelogoi}}%
        \vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil%
      }%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{%
        \hfill\smash{\raisebox{-\height}{\includelogoii}}
        \vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil%
      }%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo.  In my actual presentation, there's enough sections and the logo is small enough that, if I can get it to work, the logo should be completely contained within the section and subsection bars and not interfere with anything else.

Comment: I tried your solution, and in my small example tex file it worked if I comment out the insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal lines.  If I don't though, I get these error messages: http://i740.photobucket.com/albums/xx41/cody_messick/Screenshotfrom2014-07-22185555.png
http://i740.photobucket.com/albums/xx41/cody_messick/Screenshotfrom2014-07-22185601.png

Comment: @CodyMessick the error message is not the best thing to provide. Please compose a little *complete* document (like the one in my answer) allowing us to reproduce the problem and add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  It looks like the code I have is too long for the character limit, is there a way around that?

Comment: @CodyMessick Try reducing the code to a minimum but still allowing us to reproduce the problem. Otherwise, you can upload the code elsewhere and provide a link in your next comment so I can take a look at it in some hours.

Comment: I've uploaded the example code to google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOvGPybptpqOXptXzZoamozOVE/edit?usp=sharing

I get a missing begin{document} error on this, which is different than on my actual presentation, but I'm confident if I can get it to work on this example presentation then I can get others to work as well.

Comment: @CodyMessick The problem is a spurious `\left\ ` string in the line               `\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}\left\{ \hskip0pt plus1filll}%` ; it should be `\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%` as in my original code. Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: Oops, vim doesn't like to writing {}'s.  Thank you for catching that.  I got it working, but now the section in head/foot and subsection in head/foot got compressed to one line instead of having line breaks between each section and subsection.  What I'm hoping to get it to do is put the logos in the actual bars at the top.  I.E. have one logo to the left of the list of the sections, and have one logo to the right of the list of subsections, but within the premade "bars" that sit at the top of the frame.  Is that simply not possible?

Comment: @CodyMessick I will correct the navigation bars. And yes, what you want is possible to achieve. Give me some minutes and I'll update the answer with a option that (hopefully) gives you what you want.

Comment: @CodyMessick Please see my updated answer. I changed the redefinition of the `headline` template to have the desired behavious for the navigation bars and also simplified the code (no use of TikZ now). Hope this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for your help and your patience.

Comment: Why is `\makeatletter` useful in the answer?